# Jqgrid And Posting Filter Settings To Server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been struggling with this for a while and just can't work it out.
I'm sure its not too difficult.
I have a custom button on the tool bar that posts to a cfc. I want to post in the _search and filter. The _search is straight forward but I can't understand the syntax for the filter.
The code is this

```
      .jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", title: "Export",
      onClickButton: function() {
          $.post("scripts/records.cfc?method=getRecordsExcel&returnFormat=json", {_search:true, filters:$.filters}, function(res) {
            },"json");
      }
  })
```

Thanks for any help
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) and want to reload the grid with the data from the server using the current filters from the searching toolbar you can do this with respect of `triggerToolbar` method:

```
$("#list")[0].triggerToolbar();
```

(see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#using_the_additional_methods)).

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your reply. I'm not using the toolbar search. My backend function is expecting to receive _search and filters as parameters. I just cant work out how to post in the filter object. Thanks in advance, Mark

Comment: @cfrunningman: Which searching mode you use? Toolbar Searching used with `stringResult: true` (my standard setting by the way) for example also send `_search` and `filters` parameters. If you set just jqGrid parameters `postData.filters` to your filter and `search` to `true` and then call `.trigger('reloadGrid')` the data which you need will send to the server.

Comment: Oleg, I'm using multipleSearch:true. My search is working fine. I just want to post the search criteria to my function which creates a report server side. When I view firebug after a search I see the parameters _search and filters. But when I click my custom button I only see _search parameter and not the filter parameter (probably because my syntax is incorrect). I don't really want to reload the grid the search has already been applied. Thanks Mark

Comment: @cfrunningman: Let us you have `$grid` like `var $grid = $("#list")`. you can get value for `_search` as `$grid[0].search`. `filters` as `$grid[0].postData.filters`

Comment: If I try either $grid[0].search or $grid[0].postData.filters I get undefined. I didn't think it would be this difficult. Even console.log($grid[0].search); gives me undefined, Mark

Comment: @cfrunningman: Sorry, it should be of course `$grid[0].p.search` and `$grid[0].p.postData.filters`

Comment: @cfrunningman: You are welcome! Is the problem is solved now?